# Why is it that when you assign List X to List Y, their contents become identical?

Tags: java

I am new to java and I'm trying to take some exams to test my knowledge. One particular question kind of gotten under my skin (lol).

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();

x.add("A");
x.add("B");

List<String> y = x;
y.add("C");

System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);
```

The output I would have expected is

```
[A, B]
[A, B, C]
```

But apparently, whatever you do with Y will also happen to X. Both of them have this value now:

```
[A, B, C]
```

My first question is why? Would you happen to know any reference that I can study as to when to expect this to happen in a Java object?

Comment: There is no copy when you say `List<String> y = x;`. `y` and `x` **point** to the same `List`. For the behavior you expected, you'd need `List<String> y = new ArrayList<>(x);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch When can I expect that when I assign an Object X to Object Y, that the Object Y would just be a reference to Object X, instead of a new Object with the same value?

Comment: When you don't have a `new`, it's going to be the same `Object` reference.

Comment: If it looks like `x=y`, then it's _always_ going to be a reference to the same object.  But then if you later do `y = somethingElse()`, then the reference changes again and `x` doesn't change.